# Help with Logic to English Translations

Tags: logic

Let S be a set of people, C be the set of all countries, and let T be
a predicate defined over S × C such that T(x, y) is True if x ∈ S has
travelled to country y ∈ C. Express each of the following statements
by a simple English sentence.

• (∃x ∈ S, T(x, France)) ∧ (∀y ∈ S, T(y, Japan)).
My guess .. Some person has traveled to France and everyone has traveled to Japan

• ∀x ∈ S, ∃y ∈ C, T(x, y).
My guess.. Every person has traveled to some country

• ∀x, z ∈ S, ∃y ∈ C, T(x, y) ⇔ T(z, y).

My guess.. Every person has traveled to some country if and only if every person has traveled to some country

Some may be off.. I'm not confident so thanks for any help.

Comment: I think the last one says that for any pair, there exists a country the pair has travelled or hasn't been together?

Comment: Yes, for the last one, I agree with Jan. For every two people, there is a country in which either they have both travelled or neither of them has travelled, but not one person has and the other hasn't.

Comment: ok i see that and agree. what about first 2

Comment: The first two you got right.